# Powershell failing after Server OS Upgrade

Tags: powershell

I've had the below script running on a 2012R2 connection broker for some time without issue, however, after upgrading the connection broker to 2022, the script no longer works properly. It runs and the e-mail is received, but it's blank.

Upon investigating, I found that when manually run, I get the following:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS-Scripts\rdstats.ps1:28 char:5
+     $ob = [PSCustomObject]@{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm assuming it's the '$ob = [PSCustomObject]@{' portion that it's considering null, however, when I drop this into the powershell window:

```
foreach ( $rdhost in $rdhosts )
{
    $rdp = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $rdhost.SessionHost -Port 3389

    $ob = [PSCustomObject]@{
        CollectionName      = $rdhost.CollectionName
        SessionHost         = $rdhost.SessionHost
        InCluster           = $rdhost.NewConnectionAllowed
        RemotePort          = $rdp.RemotePort
        PortAlive           = $rdp.TcpTestSucceeded
        PingSucceeded       = $rdp.PingSucceeded
        PingReplyDetails    = $rdp.PingReplyDetails.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms"
        }

    $objs += $ob
}
```

No errors are returned.

I was able to run it from a machine running 2012R2 against the 2022 connection brokers, and that succeeded, so it seems the problem isn't with the connection broker, but likely the different Powershell versions on the 2012R2 and 2022 (4.0 vs 5.1).

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why Powershell 5.1 is apparently considering '$ob = [PSCustomObject]@{' to be null?

```
###BEGIN TODO CONFIG EMAIL

#$Username = 'user@domain.com'
#$Password = ''
$emailTo = "user@domain.com"
$bccTo = "dg@domain.com"
$emailFrom = "status@domain.com"

###END TODO CONFIG EMAIL

#$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force

# Users you password securly
#$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass 



Import-Module RemoteDesktop
$rdhosts = Get-RDSessionHost -CollectionName "RD Collection 1"

$objs = @()

foreach ( $rdhost in $rdhosts )
{
    $rdp = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $rdhost.SessionHost -Port 3389

    $ob = [PSCustomObject]@{
        CollectionName      = $rdhost.CollectionName
        SessionHost         = $rdhost.SessionHost
        InCluster           = $rdhost.NewConnectionAllowed
        RemotePort          = $rdp.RemotePort
        PortAlive           = $rdp.TcpTestSucceeded
        PingSucceeded       = $rdp.PingSucceeded
        PingReplyDetails    = $rdp.PingReplyDetails.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms"
        }

    $objs += $ob
}

$str = Out-String -InputObject $objs -Width 100

Send-MailMessage -From $emailFrom -To $emailTo -BCC $bccTo -Subject "RD Collection TS Audit" -Body $str -SmtpServer mail.domain.com -Port 25
```

Comment: It's likely because of `$rdp.PingReplyDetails.RoundtripTime.ToString()` <-- as far as I can tell, the result object from `Test-NetConnection` doesn't have a `PingReplyDetails` property in 5.1, so the `ToString()` call fails

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Removing it got the script working again, but now there's an odd anomaly. When run as the script, 'PingSucceeded' is returned as 'False', however, if I run 'Test-NetConnection -ComputerName server.domain.local' in the same Powershell window I manually ran the script in, it returns 'True'. Another odd thing I noticed is it did return a 'PingReplyDetails (RTT)' in 5.1. The output of the 'TestNetConnection' command is identical in both 4.0 and 5.1. I also found that putting 'PingReplyDetails    = $rdp.PingReplyDetails' back in, it works, but returns no data.

Comment: Adding '.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms"' back to 'rdp.PingReplyDetails' causes it to fail.

Comment: It only returns the `PingReplyDetails` property _when you use it to ping_ - when you specify `-Port XXX`, then it changes behavior and attempts a TCP connection instead. If you want full "parity" between 4.0 and 5.1 then you'll have to call `Test-NetConnection` twice :)

Comment: Thank you for the push. I really suck at scripting, coding etc, with the wild variations in syntax and whatnot, so figuring these things out is often a huge challenge for me.  Somehow, with your push, a lightbulb came on. I ended up adding '$ping = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $rdhost.SessionHost' below the '$rdp = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $rdhost.SessionHost', changing the 'PingSucceeded' line to 'PingSucceeded       = $ping.PingSucceeded' and 'PingReplyDetails' line to 'PingReplyDetails    = $ping.PingReplyDetails.RoundTripTime.ToString() + " ms"'. Now everything's coming through

Comment: That's great, you're most welcome! You should post that as an answer below! :)